# Driver's switching is confusing

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a computer with [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHc3S.jpg) properties

My problem is, I once had an ATI Radeon HD 5650 card driver installed on my computer about 2 years ago. 
After that time, eventually my driver got named as an AMD Radeon HD 5000 series in the images.

I played many games with ATI Radeon HD 5650 card driver with no inconvenience, but I can't say the same with AMD HD 5000 series. I don't have the same performance with the same games on this graphic card driver. I tried to reinstall ATI Radeon HD 5650 driver many times, but it did not work.

What is the best solution to go back and use my previous graphic card driver?

Comment: Are you using a CPU with an integrated GPU? It's possible you are looking at two separate GPUs each with its own driver.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/fHh6F    if i'm not wrong my graphic card has its own RAM..so it might be dedicated..

Comment: i had done a change with my driver like [link](http://imgur.com/a/MAZmR)